# how to update masterpage elements from child page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I want to update master page hyperlinks from child page. Here is the code i written to update

master page elements.

```
            HyperLink h1 = this.Master.FindControl("AnLogin") as HyperLink;
            h1.NavigateUrl = "#";
            h1.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
            HyperLink h2 = this.Master.FindControl("AnLogout") as HyperLink;
            h2.Text = "Logout";
            h2.NavigateUrl = "~/Logout.aspx";

            if (Session["UserType"].ToString() == "Admin")
            {

                Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");

            }
```

Master page is updating only  when i am not redirecting to another page.  If i am redirecting to another page, that hyperlinks remain same as static.

Here i need to update master page hyperlinks that should be same for all pages further i can traverse. How to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd maybe change your approach. This sounds like a candidate for a user control in place of the hyperlink. Leave the functionality of setting the NavigateUrl property up to the user control depending what page it is on.

Answer (score -1):

Here i suggest not to post back the page for such small operations. 
You can set this condition on aspx page like :-

```
<% if (Session["UserType"].ToString() == "Admin")  {%>
        // do something
    <%} else { %>
        // do something
    <%} %>
```